# Как написать пользователю discord на python?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я делаю бота. Но как мне сделать так, чтобы бот написал мне, при условии что у него нет никаких связей со мной(кроме личного чата)?
Код:

```py
import discord as ds
bot = ds.Client()
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    global game_creator
    game_creator = None#<-- Здесь
    game_creator.send("Hello")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужен конкретный пользователь, то скопируйте его `id`, нажав на него правой кнопкой мыши в дискорде. Если соответствующего пункта нет, то включите режим разработчика в настройках.

Сначала получите объект пользователя, а потом уже отправьте сообщение:

```py
game_creator = await bot.fetch_user(723849347623489348)
await game_creator.send('hello')
```

Здесь `723849347623489348` - это число, `id` пользователя.

Comment: Спасибо большое!